# Cellular blinds: Do I need to go full blackout to get thermal insulation benefits, or will light filtering do?

Tags: insulation, windows, blinds

Considering getting some cellular blinds for our south-facing rooms, which sadly only have single pane and no AC. As a result, the back of the house absolutely radiates heat into the rest (which has modern windows and AC). We do have a few oaks in the back yard which diffuse the sun from mid afternoon onward, but midday it all comes in unhampered.

Looking at these [blackout cellular blinds](https://www.selectblinds.com/cellular-shades.html?productId=881&width=22&height=42&colorId=11683&K=Color%7C2&customer_id=890-720-7779&gad=1&gclid=CjwKCAjwh8mlBhB_EiwAsztdBCh8b3I71ta1r1mYp9dC05wuElAvZWo0rvbRKVjvNSawu7nAe49z4hoCxksQAvD_BwE) vs something like these [light filtering cellular blinds](https://www.selectblinds.com/cellular-shades.html?K=Color%7C23&Page=2) at half the price. (Neither of these are affiliate links, I have no financial interest beyond wanting some blinds!)

Obviously, the price of the latter is more attractive for multiple windows (We have at least 5 windows we'd like to treat this way, but could justify another 5 just as easily). And moreover, I DO actually like the back of the house getting some natural light.

But, if the light filtering is going to undermine the entire point of this expenditure, I'll just go blackout and be done with it. Please understand that I am not looking for a silver bullet, just need something to lower the temp a few degrees during the day until I can fix my ductwork in that part of the house.

Sorry if this is a super basic question, but I hope y'all might have some insight! TYIA

Comment: Have you asked the respective manufacturers about this (or simply read their product brochures)?

Comment: Ask the manufacturer, distributor or seller for the R-values of the two styles. The higher the R-value, the better it is at reducing heat gain. I lived in a house for 1 year that had sunny windows in the morning. The 2-layer cellular shades were very effective at slowing the AM temperature rise. They were white on the outside and were not blackout-style.

Answer (score 1):

TLDR: Blinds won't prevent heat from entering the room, unless the exterior side is white.

The #1 enemy of air conditioning is **solar gain**.  Sunlight provides 1000 watts per square meter of heat = 300 BTU/hr per square foot.  And the sun travels across the sky, but the slow-changing thermal mass of the building tends to protect you in the mornings.  Once the building is nice and hot, that *stored* solar gain in the building's mass continues to invade the building long after sundown.   Insulation slows the invasion of this heat, and gives it time to shed some heat to the air outside, but this is why your A/C is still cranking hard even after sundown, and why it works the hardest when solarization is dropping off sharply.

If you have forced-air with the A/C having the same ducting as the heater, the duct balancing needed for heat (when solar gain is not a player) is *very* different than the duct balancing needed to resist *solar gain*.  That's why this drives everyone so crazy.  Your HVAC system isn't broken, well its inherent design is broken by lacking zone controls. But this was considered a miracle when designed in the 1930s - then, "sleeping porches" were an actual thing.

The best way to get rid of that solar gain is to reflect it.  The whitest white paints have about an 80% albedo (reflection) so only 20% gets through.  The typical off-white pastels people like to paint houses are closer to 50% albedo (not good).  The aesthetically preferred red, brown, gray etc. roofs **have less than 10% albedo** so they are a total gong-show at rejecting solar gain.

Walls and roof, at least, get warm on the outside and then radiate some of that heat to nearby outside air.  Windows simply pass it right through. So now it's inside the house warming whatever it touches.

To any extent you can whiten the sides or roof of the building, will help overall.  While the windows may be the most obvious entry, the roof and walls are much larger, and worse, that heat *lingers*.

If you install heavy curtains, you will simply get "hot curtains" inside your room. It won't reflect much unless the curtain liner is white on the outside.  Putting films on your windows will just get you hot windows (the double-pane will still do its best to keep the heat on the side with the film).  Ultimately, all sunlight turns into heat (entropy works that way), so any sunlight that isn't reflected will turn into heat in the room.  Laws of thermodynamics.

Another option is shade structures outside, that shade the windows and then are cooled by outdoor air.

Comment: That's a lot of interesting info, and I thank you for sharing it. But it doesn't really answer my immediate question even if it gives a lot of stellar advice for holistic cooling solutions.

Comment: @thecelloronin sorry, I was trying to say that blinds will do basically nothing to cool the room, which I thought was your primary goal. You'll just get "hot blinds" instead of "hot other stuff in the room".  Unless they're white, of course.

Comment: Awning(s) over the window(s) in question, i.e. keeping direct sunlight away from the window(s) would help more than any blinds.